# SQL Server - create a password policy that requires at least 12 characters

Tags: sql-server, password-policy

I am looking to implement restriction on password length in SQL Server (version 2012 to onward):

SQL Server:

- create a password policy that requires at least 12 characters
- Enforce minimum length of password to N number of characters

what can be possible options in sql server for it?

creation of any trigger, or procedure? or function (like oracle)? or some other way.

would be thankful for any guidelines

best regards

Comment: SQL Server `LOGIN`s already have a policy on them for strength, it's only if you create with with `CHECK_POLICY` set to `OFF` that can provide a weaker password. This is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: The default password policy only requires 8 characters but otherwise I would just use what is already available instead of recreating the wheel.